# Spark error - Decimal precision 39 exceeds max precision 38

Tags: r, oracle, apache-spark

When I try to collect data from Spark dataframe, I get an error stating

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Decimal
>   precision 39 exceeds max precision 38".

All the data which is in Spark dataframe is from Oracle database, where I believe decimal precision is <38. Is there any way I can achieve this without modifying the data?

```
# Load required table into memory from Oracle database
df <- loadDF(sqlContext, source = "jdbc", url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:usr/pass@url.com:1521" , dbtable = "TBL_NM")

RawData <- df %>% 
    filter(DT_Column > DATE(‘2015-01-01’))

RawData <- as.data.frame(RawData)
```

Gives error

Below is the stacktrace:

> WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 10.**.**.***,
>   executor 0): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed:
>   Decimal precision 39 exceeds max precision 38 at
>   scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224) at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal.set(Decimal.scala:113) at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal$.apply(Decimal.scala:426) at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3$$anonfun$9.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:337)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3$$anonfun$9.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:337)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$nullSafeConvert(JdbcUtils.scala:438)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:337)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:335)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:286)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:268)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287) at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87) at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99) at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Please suggest any solution. Thank you.

Comment: Did you got a solution to this ?
I am stuck with the same issue using Python and Spark-2.4

Comment: Hoping this has been solved by somebody somewhere as well...

Answer (score 4):

Ran across this with AWS Glue and Postgres.  There was a bug in Spark 2.1.0 that fixed it for most people, but someone posted a workaround in the comments about using a [customSchema option](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20427?focusedCommentId=16942090&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16942090).

I had a similar issue with AWS Glue and Spark SQL: I was calculating a currency amount so the result was a float.  Glue threw the error `Decimal precision 1 exceeds max precision -1` even though the Glue Data Catalog defined the column as a decimal.  Took a page from the above customSchema solution by explicitly casting the column as NUMERIC(10,2) and Spark stopped complaining.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Since this error is not only related to a particular DB (In my case I was querying Singlestore DB using Pyspark and got the same error)
`pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: DECIMAL precision 57 exceeds max precision 38`.

I solved it by casting the `amount` column in my sql statement as below:

```
SELECT
  '${etl_day}' AS day,
  id,
  CAST(SUM(amount) AS DECIMAL(32, 8)) * -0.01 AS sum_amount
FROM
  table
WHERE
  record_date >= '${etl_day}'
  AND record_date < DATE_ADD('${etl_day}', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY
  1,2
```