# Spark error - Decimal precision 39 exceeds max precision 38 (I know its duplicate but have no solution)

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark, odbc

When trying to load data from JDBC(Oracle) into Spark, there seems to be precision loss in the decimal field, as per my understanding Spark supports DECIMAL(38,18). The field from the Oracle is DECIMAL(38,14), whereas Spark rounds off the last four digits making it a precision of DECIMAL(38,10). This is happening to only one field in the dataframe whereas in the same query another field populates the right schema.

```
import oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

    jdbcDF = spark.read \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url","ORACLE") \
        .option("dbtable","QUERY") \
        .option("user","USERNAME") \
        .option("password","PASSWORD") \
        .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver") \
        .load()

jdbc.write.mode("overwrite")
              .parquet("/path")
```

Error StackTrace:

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 10...***, executor 0): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Decimal precision 39 exceeds max precision 38 at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224) at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal.set(Decimal.scala:113) at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal$.apply(Decimal.scala:426) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3$$anonfun$9.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:337) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3$$anonfun$9.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:337) at
```

Comment: From [this potential duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130460/) does [this bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20427) help at all?

Comment: Other potential duplicates [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53074721), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462377/), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991249)].